# Insert QTextBox without new line

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a list of strings which I want to put in a QTextEdit as QTextBlocks. The thing is I don't want them to be on different lines. Here's my code for now:

```
text = get_strings()

for block_text in text:
    cursor.insertBlock()
    cursor.insertText(block_text)

    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.End)
    cursor.removeSelectedText()

cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Start)
```

Comment: Moving the cursor to the end is wrong and pointless for this, and *you* are creating different lines by doing `insertBlock()`. Besides, why don't you just do `cursor.insertText(' '.join(text))` without any for loop at all?

Comment: A text-block ***is*** a line/paragraph. If the strings contain newlines, you firstly need to strip all those out and join everything together with spaces so you generate a single text-block: `text = ' '.join(' '.join(map(str.split, get_strings())))`. Then you can simply do `editor.setText(text)`.